# What signal to listen to for new Many-To-One relations?

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-one, django-signals

```
from django.db import models

class Reporter(models.Model):
    pass

class Article(models.Model):
    reporter = models.ForeignKey(Reporter, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

With the models above, what signal should I listen to if I want to know when an article is added to a reporter?

```
>>> new_article = Article()
>>> new_reporter = Reporter()
>>> new_reporter.article_set.add(new_article)
```

I've tried both [`m2m_changed`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/signals/#m2m-changed) and [`post_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save) but neither works

```
from django.db.models.signals import m2m_changed, post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(m2m_changed)
def m2m_add(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    print "m2m_add triggered!"

@receiver(post_save)
def post_save_add(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    print "post_save_add triggered!"
```

Answer (score 1):

Connect to  `post_save` of `Article`, but you have to [call `add` with `bulk=False`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add):

```
new_reporter.article_set.add(new_article, bulk=False)
# will not use update and call save on article instance
```

Comment: Tried that, nothing is triggered.

Comment: This works, however, isn't there anyway to listen for signals when calling `add` with `bulk=True`?

Comment: I don't think so. If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/query.py) of `update`, there are no signals being send.

Comment: Could I write my own signal that triggers when adding to that specific field (with `bulk=True`)?

Comment: You can subclass `QuerySet`, override `update`, `bulk_create`, etc (call super() and send some signal). Then you have to give your model a custom manager which uses your custom queryset class.